# freeRTOS xTimerCreate invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'const signed char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, timer, freertos

Hi many thanks for your contribution,
I added the code to create a task timer that I need to run some
work regularly, when I compile it gives me an error,i do not understand how to solve it, I looked in the various discussions but i could not find anything.

```
    #include “esp_common.h”
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include “esp_wps.h”
    #include “freertos/timers.h”
    #include “freertos/FreeRTOS.h”
    #include “freertos/task.h”
    #include “freertos/queue.h”

    xTimerHandle timer;

    void callback_timer (xTimerHandle xTimer)
    {
    }

    timer = xTimerCreate("timer",5000/portTICK_RATE_MS,pdTRUE,(void *)0, 
    callback_timer);
```

[Clang IntelliSense] Error: no matching function for call to 'xTimerCreate'

Errore invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'const signed char*' [-fpermissive]

[image]

Please help me

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the "timer" string to const signed char

The code will look like this:

```
timer = xTimerCreate((const signed char *)"timer",5000/portTICK_RATE_MS,pdTRUE,(void *)0, 
callback_timer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of stathisv
I'm not very experienced, could you write me the instruction as it should be written timer ... = .... xTimerCreate ....?
Many thanks